# Modify string in bash to contain new line character?

Tags: python, bash, google-api

I am using a bash script to call google-api's upload_video.py (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video )

I have a mp4 called output.mp4 which I would like to upload.

The problem is I cannot get my array to work how I would like.

This new line character is "required" because my arguments to python script contain spaces.

Here is a simplified version of my bash script:

```
# Operator may change these
hold=100
location="Foo, Montana "
declare -a file_array=("unique_ID_0" "unique_ID_1")

upload_file=upload_file.txt
upload_movie=output.mp4

# Hit enter at end b/c \n not recognized
upload_title=$location' - '${file_array[0]}' - Hold '$hold' Sweeps 
'
upload_description='The spectrum recording was made in at '$location'.
'
# Overwrite with 1st call > else apppend >>
echo "$upload_title" > $upload_file
echo "$upload_description" >> $upload_file

# Load each line of text file into array
IFS=$'\n'
cmd_google=$(<$upload_file) 
unset IFS

nn=1
for i in "${cmd_google[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    # Delete last character: \n 
    #i=${i[-nn]%?}
    #i=${i: : -nn}
    #i=${i::${#i}-nn}
    i=${i%?}
    #i=${i#"\n"}
    #i=${i%"\n"}
    echo "$i"
done

python upload_video.py --file=$upload_movie --title="${cmd_google[0]}" --description="${cmd_google[1]}"
```

At first I attempted to remove the new line character, but it appears that the enter or \n is not working how I would like, each line is not separate.  It writes the title and description as one line.

How do I modify my bash script to recognize a newline character?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to copy-paste the shortest possible **complete** bash script that illustrates your problem. Please change any credentials to "XXXX" to avoid telling us your password. See [ask] and [mcve] for more information about writing questions that elicit good answers.

Comment: HTTP Error 400 is a "bad request" error. So to know why you get an error we need to know what request you send.

Comment: Sorry, I hit post before I meant to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler than you are making it.

```
# Operator may change these
hold=100
location="Foo, Montana"
declare -a file_array=("unique_ID_0" "unique_ID_1")

upload_file=upload_file.txt
upload_movie=output.mp4

upload_title="$location - ${file_array[0]} - Hold $hold Sweeps"
upload_description="The spectrum recording was made in at $location."

cat <<EOF > "$upload_file"
$upload_title
$upload_description
EOF

# ...

readarray -t cmd_google < "$upload_file"

python upload_video.py --file="$upload_movie" --title="${cmd_google[0]}" --description="${cmd_google[1]}"
```

I suspect the `readarray` command is all you are really looking for, since much of the above code is simply creating a file that I assume you are receiving already created.

Comment: Hi @chepner, I used your script but I get an error, readarray: command not found.  I am using minGW msys bash on windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: However, I do agree it's much simpler.  What I am getting from you script which I did not undersatnd before how you are creating the upload_title variable.

Comment: And surrounding each call with the double-quotes, --file="$upload_movie".  These are they types of syntax issues which brought me to my too-complex workaround to begin with. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help from chepner's answer. My question hid the fact that I wanted to write new line characters into the video's description.

Instead of adding a new line character in the bash script, it is much easier to have a text file which contains the correctly formatted script and read it in, then concatenate it with run-time specific variable.

In my case the correctly formatted text is called description.txt:

[Here is a snip of my description.txt which contains newline characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNsux.png)

Here is my final version of the script:

```
# Operator may change these
hold=100
location="Foo, Montana"
declare -a file_array=("unique_ID_0" "unique_ID_1")

upload_title="$location - ${file_array[0]} - Hold $hold Sweeps"
upload_description="The spectrum recording was made in at $location. "
# Read in script which contains newline
temp=$(<description.txt)
# Concatenate them
upload_description="$upload_description$temp"

upload_movie=output.mp4

python upload_video.py --file="$upload_movie" --title="$upload_title" --description="$upload_description"
```